# SQLiteQueryBuilder multiple selection

Tags: android

How to I add multiple selections (where clauses) to a SQLliteQueryBuilder query? For example, 
(age between 10 and 20 AND height = 60) OR (sex = 'F')

```
public Cursor query (SQLiteDatabase db, String[] projectionIn, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String sortOrder)

selection   A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given URL.
selectionArgs   You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they appear in the selection. The values will be bound as Strings.
```

Answer (score 10):

Basically you pass conditions in the `selection` String, you mention like

```
String selection = "arg1 = ? and arg2 = ?" ...
```

and the `selectionArgs` is String array, so the selection values are given here:

```
selectionArgs[0] = "value of arg1";
selectionArgs[1] = "value of arg2";

and so on
```

So you can use:

```
String selection = "Age between ? and ? and Height = ?";
selectionArgs[0] = "10";
selectionArgs[1] = "20";
selectionArgs[2] = "168";
```

And then pass these strings to `query`.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. QueryBuilder is smarter than I thought. It parses parenthesis intelligently.

Comment: I'll upvote you since he clearly didn't accept. I hate helping people that have so low rep points, you know that they aren't going to help you back by clicking a button.